# how to boot system normally

Tags: 12.04, gdm

I have serious problem with my ubuntu system. Yesterday, I installed gdm and set it default display manager, when I rebooted grub menu display I boot to normal boot but only black screen show.Please help I want my system up and running.

Comment: It is simply impossible as question title clearly describe how to uninstall gdm from grub

Comment: @farooq can you login usin ctrl + alt+f1

Comment: @ nux, I cannot login using ctrl + alt+f1

Comment: Is there any way to system up and running. I dont want to reinstall ubuntu. Please help